# How to set dropdown value from query string in fabric dropdown

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, query-string, office-ui-fabric-react

i am trying to set value in  dropdown from  query string but unable to do so , below is the code

```
private SelectReferralFromQueryString(name) {
   name = this.GetParameterValues('Country');

  if (name != false) {

      name = decodeURIComponent(name);
      //here name comes correct as Keith T. What should I do from here?
  }

}
private GetParameterValues(param) {
  var url = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
  for (var i = 0; i < url.length; i++) {
      var urlparam = url[i].split('=');
      if (urlparam[0] == param) {
          return urlparam[1];
      }
      else
          return false;
  }
}



<Dropdown
        placeholder="Select an option"
        selectedKey={this.SelectReferralFromQueryString(name)}
        label="TRAVELLING TO"
        options={this.state.ddlCountry}
        styles={dropdownStyles}
        onChange={(_, optionSelected) => {this.DataBind(optionSelected.key,'TravelTo');
        
        }}
      />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SelectReferralFromQueryString method does not require the name parameter,you could remove it.

My test code:

```
<Dropdown
        placeholder="Select an option"
        label="Basic uncontrolled example"
        options={options}
        styles={dropdownStyles}
        onChange={(event,options,index)=>console.log(event,options,index)}
        
        selectedKey={this.state.names}
      />
private  SelectReferralFromQueryString(){
     var names=[];
     var name;
    name = this.GetParameterValues('Country');
 
   if (name != false) {
 
       name = decodeURIComponent(name);
       //create an array to save country name
       names.unshift(name);
       //save the array to state
       this.setState({names})
   }
 
 }
 private GetParameterValues(param) {
   var url = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
   for (var i = 0; i < url.length; i++) {
       var urlparam = url[i].split('=');
       if (urlparam[0] == param) {
           return urlparam[1];
       }
       else
           return false;
   }
 }
```